# How to update Ubuntu server automatically when server is powered on?

Tags: upgrade, updates, automation, unattended-upgrades

I have scenario when Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server is powered on every day for 1 hour.

How to setup it in the way, that **when started it updates itself automatically** with an automatic reboot if needed?

Note: by updating I mean - keeping system up to date. Similar to running apt-get dist-upgrade (or similar, so that at least security updates are installed).

Comment: You can check those config files in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/, especially 50unattended-upgrades

Comment: I know about "unattended-upgrades" package, but I am not sure that it will update the server when it is powered on only for one hour during a day. Is there any reliable config, that guarantees that updates are installed on boot?

Comment: how about Unattended-Upgrade::InstallOnShutdown "true";

Comment: @alfred - it is not exactly what I am looking for. But I will use it, if nothing else comes up. Also, will it update Ubuntu on ```sudo reboot```? Does it counts as a shutdown?

Comment: I personally don't know if Ubuntu or apt or unattended-upgrades themselves give a solution for your case. If you really want to install updates right after reboot, from my knowledge, you can write a crontab job to run at boot, and do "apt update" and "unattended-upgrades" when network is ready(you also need some way to check network before doing update, or a systemd service after network-online.target).  For your question about reboot, I think it will, bases on some google result. I don't use that, so I'm not sure what its behavior is.

Comment: @alfred - thanks for the answers! Reading a little more about cron + apt and cron-apt, etc., I am certain that I will go with official way of unattended upgrades, and most probably with InstallOnShutdown as you suggested. Otherwise, the update process can break in unexpected ways, and the standard way feels more safe/stable.